# Is there an online program that can type pinyin for traditional Chinese?

Tags: pinyin, traditional-characters, simplified-characters, traditional-vs-simplified

I studied pinyin so I naturally type simplified Chinese but now I want to type traditional Chinese. Is there a program available where I can type traditional Chinese using Pinyin method? Thanks

Comment: If you are looking for an __online__ application: https://translate.google.com Set the input language to Chinese and then select 'Chinese - Traditional, Taiwan - Pinyin' in the input tool dropdown. But I guess you are better off with a desktop IME. If you have Windows, you can setup the IME very easily, it's already on your computer you just need to google that. Or perhaps you have another OS, just seach for 'Chinese Traditional IME Pinyin + [your OS]'

Comment: It seems you're not actually asking for an online service, but rather something you can download? If you're actually asking for an online IME, try this one: http://www.pinyinput.com/?lang=en

Comment: Hi, essentially I am looking for a direct input method IME where i can skip the google translate step.  However, it seems google may be the safest bet.

Answer (score 4):

I use Sogou input, there's a preference setting for it. And I believe many Chinese input have it too.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

OK, again in mac os x, go to system preferences⋯keyboard⋯input sources⋯press +⋯choose "chinese-traditional" from the left⋯then choose "pinyin - traditional", voila :)

remember to check the "show input menu in menu bar", then you can choose the pinyin as input method, and type "out" traditional chinese characters.

have fun :)

Comment: I am not a mac user.

Comment: then, consider to change :)

the built-in functions of mac os x are excellent; for learning cantonese, and/r traditional chinese.

Comment: yes thank you, I will definitely consider using a mac as well as my pc. Thanks

Comment: @Genevieve I will write an answer for Windows for you.

Comment: @Genevieve Done. Can't believe it took me 40 minutes to write this seemingly easy answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution for Windows 8.1**

1. Go to `Control Panel\Clock, Language, and Region\Language` (Alternatively, click the downward arrow on the language bar (on the taskbar) to open
   the menu and click `Settings...`)
2. Click `Add a language`
3. Select `Chinese (Simplified)`
4. Select `Chinese (Simplified, China)`
5. Once `中文(中华人民共和国)` is available as a language, click `Options`
   following it.
6. Under `Input`, `Microsoft Pinyin` should appear by default. If it is not there, click `Add an input method` and select `Microsoft Pinyin`.
7. Once `Microsoft Pinyin` is available as an input method, click
   `Options` following it.
8. Under `Choose character set`, select `Traditional Chinese`.
9. Congratulations! You can now type traditional Chinese with Pinyin. You can also press `shift` to switch between English and Chinese when `Chinese (Simplified, China)` is selected.

---

**Note**

- This answer only considers what you can achieve in native Windows system (i.e. no third-party apps). In fact, the lack of native support for Pinyin as an input method for traditional Chinese has been repeatedly complained by users.
- There is no easy method to switch between simplified Chinese and
  traditional Chinese using this method. You have to go through the
  same process again to change from one character set to another (you can keep the "Options" window open for quick switching).
- It is possible to add tradition Chinese as a language and then select "Microsoft Bopomofo" as an input method. But note that although "Microsoft Bopomofo" is based on Pinyin, it is different from "Microsoft Pinyin" and is rather clunky to use.
- Some characters outputted by "Microsoft Pinyin" using traditional Chinese character set is incorrect. For example, "只 (only)" is written the same way in both simplified Chinese and traditional Chinese. But "Microsoft Pinyin" will outputted it as "衹". There is no easy way around this problem and you have to spot it by yourself.
- A fail-proof way is to type in simplified Chinese and then copy the result into Google Translate to translate them into traditional Chinese. This comes handy when you only need to type a small number of characters (note that Google Translate will mess up your formatting), or when you need to be absolutely sure that what you are typing is 100% correct.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am translating chunks of English to Chinese, I will type in pinyin and translate via google translate to change into traditional.  Many kind thanks again.

Comment: @Genevieve Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

[Google Pinyin](http://www.google.com/intl/zh-CN/ime/pinyin/) is another option for you.

In Windows, switch your input method to Google Pinyin, and then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to switch to traditional Chinese mode. Now you can type pinyin to get traditional Chinese characters.

[image]

You can easily switch back-and-forth between simplified and traditional characters by using the same keyboard combination above.

Answer (score 0):

just remembered to remind you, there're differences between fonts for simplified and traditional chinese. since you're not mac user, i would suggest downloading google font: "not sans cjk":

https://www.google.com/get/noto/help/cjk/

or, https://www.google.com/get/noto/#sans-hant

it's free, have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

there is an app for typing Chinese made for Chinese people. search Sogou pinyin in google and it will take you to the home page of the app, download and install(un tick the Sogou browser because you probably don't want it, it's practically a Chinese version for Chrome) don't worry about it being illegal, it's not. after installing, you can just press ctrl + shift + f to change into traditional Chinese and same keys to change back. there are a lot of other cool settings and skins that comes with the app.
I recommend this app to all people who type Chinese it is really handy.
http://pinyin.sogou.com/
this is the website, go in click the button that says 立即下载 and it will start downloading. and just install it with your own preferred setting and you're good to go.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Sadly this only support Windows and XP, sorry Mac people

Answer (score 0):

### Online input method

- Mandarin pinyin → Traditional Chinese: http://www.pinyinput.com/
- Cantonese pinyin → Traditional Chinese: http://www.cantoneseinput.com/